Fantasy manga/manhwa where a female schoolmate is about to flunk out
MC has a female classmate/schoolmate in a school. I can't remember exactly if it was some sort of adventurer school or like a royal academy type of school. Her backstory was that she lived in a remote village when she was young and the whole village found out that she was talented in magic or something. So, they decided to pool in money to get her enrolled in the best school to foster her talent.
Back to the present, I think she was about to flunk out of the school because she couldn't keep up with her studies. She is afraid of facing her family and the whole village because she could not live to their expectations.
